# Converter data vinda do banco no AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Gostaria de converter a data vinda do banco (2012-02-10) para padrão brasileiro (10/02/2012) no success do AJAX, exemplo:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "crud/consulta.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.dataFiltro').val(data.data);
            // AQUI ALGUMA CONVERSÃO
});
```

Ou alguma forma de fazer a conversão no input do formulário, sendo que, esse valor será preenchido em um input. Alguma sugestão w

Comment: Explode ela com o `split` e muda a ordem, assim [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vxyzqf4/2/)

Comment: Obrigado William.

Comment: Recomendo usar expressão regular. `data.data.replace(/^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)$/, "$3/$2/$1")`.

Comment: Como faria com um campo de data e hora?

Comment: Quando dizes _"data vinda do banco (2012-02-10)"_ o formato é sempre esse? Como estás a montar a hora no servidor?

Comment: Viste a minha pergunta aqui? ^

Comment: Por exemplo, o formato sempre vem (2012-02-10 12:25:50) preciso converter para 10/02/2012 12:25:50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso de um campo data e hora:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="dataFiltro" />
```

Você não precisa converter, apenas concatena a data com a hora:

```
...
success: function(data) {
    var novaData = data.data;
    novaData = novaData + "T15:35"; //exibirá no formato: 07/07/2016 15:35
    $('.dataFiltro').val(novaData);
}
...
```

Comment: Como faria com um campo de data e hora?

Comment: Editei o que tinha postado, para exibir no campo tipo data e hora.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode converter a data na query e já trazer a mesma com o formato correto.

Comment: Na query ou no serviço que pega os valores da query e escreve no JSON. Em geral é sempre bom definir o formato correto já no servidor, ainda que se use um campo `datetime` na tela.